# how do I save samples in an array or matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I am okay with Python, Numpy but trying R and this seemingly simple operation has me stuck in R.

This is what I have but I get a `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error.

```
# find sample variance with n
samples <- matrix(0, nrow=num_samples, ncol=samp_size)
for(i in 1:10000){
  temp <- sample(population, samp_size, replace=TRUE)
  samples[i] = temp
}
samples[0]
```

I am not hung up on using matrices, can be an array or vector or list or anything but just some standard ways of doing this because searching online did not give me a quick answer for this basic operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to initialize `samples` with your actual samples:

```
set.seed(123)
n_samples <- 5
n_obs <- 10
population <- letters

samples <- matrix(sample(population, n_obs*n_samples, replace=TRUE),  
                  nrow=n_samples, ncol=n_obs)
```

But to do it the way you've started, you just need to let R know you'd like to put entries into all columns of `samples`, like this: `samples[i,  ]`.

It's similar to using `:` syntax in Numpy: `array[i, :]`.

```
samples <- matrix(0, nrow=n_samples, ncol=n_obs)

for(i in 1:n_samples){
  temp <- sample(population, n_obs, replace=TRUE)
  samples[i,] = temp
}
```

Either way, the output is the same:

```
samples
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "h"  "u"  "k"  "w"  "y"  "b"  "n"  "x"  "o"  "l"  
[2,] "y"  "l"  "r"  "o"  "c"  "x"  "g"  "b"  "i"  "y"  
[3,] "x"  "s"  "q"  "z"  "r"  "s"  "o"  "p"  "h"  "d"  
[4,] "z"  "x"  "r"  "u"  "a"  "m"  "t"  "f"  "i"  "g"  
[5,] "d"  "k"  "k"  "j"  "d"  "d"  "g"  "m"  "g"  "w"
```

Comment: I actually had that slice syntax with comma in there before taking it out but I'm going to try directly assigning skipping `temp` if possible.

Comment: omg, I was like "this doesn't work" trying to access `samples[0]` where R indexing starts at 1 :)

Comment: I had already opened a jupyter notebook and started the same problem with numpy but I'll keep trying R for a bit longer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replicate?

```
samples <- t(replicate(n = num_samples, sample(population, samp_size, replace=TRUE),simplify = "array"))
```

This will return a matrix of the dimensions samp_size x num_samples.

Comment: Do you have a link to a good R reference textbook?  A lot of the online stuff goes straight into examples so if what I want to do is not similar, I get stuck.\

Comment: I would recommend this for introduction https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/index.html and this for tidyverse tools: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html. I hope that helps.

Comment: It does tremendously.